# AWS S3 incorrect bucket object

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload in image to s3 using the `aws-sdk`. I'm able to retrieve my bucket

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
resp = s3.list_buckets
bucket = resp.buckets.select {|x| x.name == "mybucket"}[0]

>> bucket
>> #<struct Aws::S3::Types::Bucket name="mybucket", creation_date=2015-09-05 19:23:49 UTC>
```

I now have my bucket. Looking at the [aws](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html#presigned_post-instance_method) documentation and [heroku's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) documentation I should be able to call `bucket.presigned_post`, however I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'presigned_post' for #<Aws::S3::Types::Bucket:0x007ff583bece10>`

What am I missing here? Do I not have the correct s3 bucket object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Aws::S3::Types::Bucket` is not the same as `Aws::S3::Bucket`. Only the latter has `#presigned_post`. It appears that `Aws::S3::Client#list_buckets` returns *information about buckets*, not the bucket objects (which you have to create yourself).

Have you tried:

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new('mybucket', client: s3)
```